# matching string then returning results using regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Is there a way to match the following string so I get `user name` and 50?

```
hey "user name":/users/50
```

I may also have more than one instance of this in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following

```
string = 'hey "user name":/users/50'
matches = string.scan /"(?<name>[A-Za-z ]+)":\/users\/(?<user_id>\d+)/
```

`matches` will be an array containing arrays with 2 elements where the first element is the name and the 2nd element is the user_id

```
>> matches # [['user name', 50]]
```